# Is it possible to change the values in the form which was shown for multiple times

Tags: c#, winforms

I am having a form which will be shown on leaving the control of the previous form. Suppose my form1 have a textbox i will enter a value as 2 there immediately after leaving i will show form2 there i will have some textboxes out of them i will have a sequence number which should be autoincremented like if i have 0001 in that on initial load after clicking save i will show the same form untill it matches the previous value what i need is when the user clicks on save i would like to auto increment the textbox value can any one give me an idea

My code is as follows

Form2 save button

```
 private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (filecontrolvariables.m_Addendaclick == true)
        {
            objCTXAddenda.Addenda_RecordTypeCode = txtRectypecode.Text;
            objCTXAddenda.Addendatypecode = txtAddendaTypeCode.Text;
            objCTXAddenda.PaymentRelatedInformation = txtPaymentRelInfo.Text;
            objCTXAddenda.Addendasequencenumber = txtAddendaSeqNo.Text;
            objCTXAddenda.EntryDetailSequenceNumber = txtEntryDetailSeqNumber.Text;
            Append.addendawithentry++;
            objCTXAddenda.saveAddenda(Append.FileName);
            this.Close();
            frmMain.loadAddenda("Addenda", true);
        }
        else
        {
            timeBeforeClose--;

            if (timeBeforeClose == 0)
            {
                txtAddendaSeqNo.Text = Append.AddendaSequenceno.ToString("0000");
                objCTXAddenda.Addenda_RecordTypeCode = txtRectypecode.Text;
                objCTXAddenda.Addendatypecode = txtAddendaTypeCode.Text;
                objCTXAddenda.PaymentRelatedInformation = txtPaymentRelInfo.Text;
                objCTXAddenda.Addendasequencenumber = txtAddendaSeqNo.Text;
                objCTXAddenda.EntryDetailSequenceNumber = txtEntryDetailSeqNumber.Text;
                objCTXAddenda.saveAddenda(Append.FileName);
                txtPaymentRelInfo.Text = string.Empty;
                this.Close();// I will close the form when this matches
                Append.addendawithentry++;
            }
            else
            {
                objCTXAddenda.Addenda_RecordTypeCode = txtRectypecode.Text;
                objCTXAddenda.Addendatypecode = txtAddendaTypeCode.Text;
                objCTXAddenda.PaymentRelatedInformation = txtPaymentRelInfo.Text;
                objCTXAddenda.Addendasequencenumber = txtAddendaSeqNo.Text;
                objCTXAddenda.EntryDetailSequenceNumber = txtEntryDetailSeqNumber.Text;
                objCTXAddenda.saveAddenda(Append.FileName);
                txtPaymentRelInfo.Text = string.Empty;
                Append.addendawithentry++;
                Append.AddendaSequenceno++;

            }
        }
    }
```

When form loads but for the second time as it is not loading i can not increment

```
private void frmAddenda_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Append.addendawithentry = 0;
        if (filecontrolvariables.m_Addendaclick == true)
        {
            btnCancel.Visible = true;
            Append.AddendaSequenceno++;
            StringBuilder sbEmpty = new StringBuilder();
            Append.sbEntryAddenda = sbEmpty;
            txtRectypecode.Text = ((char)55).ToString();
            txtAddendaTypeCode.Text = "05";
            txtAddendaSeqNo.Text = Append.AddendaSequenceno.ToString("0000");
        }
        else
        {
            btnCancel.Visible = false;
            Append.AddendaSequenceno++;
            StringBuilder sbEmpty = new StringBuilder();
            Append.sbEntryAddenda = sbEmpty;
            txtRectypecode.Text = ((char)55).ToString();
            txtAddendaTypeCode.Text = "05";
            if (!(timeBeforeClose == 0))
                txtAddendaSeqNo.Text = Append.AddendaSequenceno.ToString("0000");
            else
                txtAddendaSeqNo.Text = Append.AddendaSequenceno.ToString("0000");
        }
    }
```

Prev form code

```
private void txtNoOfAddenda_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        filecontrolvariables.m_Addendaclick = false;
        pass();
        if (Convert.ToInt16(txtNoOfAddenda.Text) == Convert.ToInt16(((char)48).ToString()))
        {
            txtAddendarecord.Text = ((char)48).ToString();
        }
        else
            txtAddendarecord.Text = ((char)49).ToString();
    }

  private void pass()
    {
        string traceNo = string.Empty;
        i = 0;
        if (!int.TryParse(txtNoOfAddenda.Text, out i))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter numeric value betewwn(0-9999)");
            txtNoOfAddenda.Focus();
        }
        else
        {
            if (i > 0)
            {
                traceNo = txtTraceNo.Text.Substring(8, 7);
                frmAddenda frmAddenda = new frmAddenda(i, traceNo);
                frmAddenda.ShowDialog();
                txtNoOfAddenda.Leave -= txtNoOfAddenda_Leave;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: I read the question twice and don't think I really understand it, so I'll just leave a comment... Have you considered a `static` member variable that you increment each time the form is shown? Then you can just display this value in the textbox.

Comment: Ya i did that but i can not show that in the textbox as the form is not getting loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am not able to understand your problem completely but wants to suggest you on what i understood.

what i understand is that you wants to increment value of your textbox of form1 on click of form2's save button.
to do so follow below steps:

make that textbox of form1 to public in which you wants value from form1.
create an object of form1 in form2 like:

```
Form1 f1;
```

now when you shows form2 on lostfocus from your form1's textbox. before showing form2 do following:

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
f2.f1 = this;
f2.showdialog() or you can use f2.show();
```

now in form2 on click of save button write below code:

```
f1.yourPublicTextBox.text = "any value which you wants on textbox";
```

or as you said you wants to autoincrement it then

```
f1.yourPublicTextBox.text = (Convert.ToInt32(yourPublicTextBox.text) + 1).toString();
```

and its done..

EDIT:

do not let the form2 close because on close of form2 your object of form2 will become null. so just hide it and show it again.

so below code is showing that on click of close button we are not let user allowing to close form we are just hiding it and you can show it again when ever it required.

```
private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                this.Hide();
            }
```

Comment: What i need is if i enter a value in the textbox of form1 as 2 on leave event i write my code to show the form2 on form2 i will autoincrement textbox it should be get incremented but as per my condition if enter 2 in form1 the second form will be shown 2 times and the user can not close it untill my condition satisifies but i would like to display the auto id on every save click on form2

Comment: @Dorababu: lets go step by step. confirm me first requirement is that, if you enters 2 in form1's textbox then 2 instances of form2 should be open?

Comment: Ya and when the second form loaded the code i posted else part executes and the textbox text will be as 0001

Comment: @Dorababu: create a class and take a public static variable. set value in it from any form and you will be able to get it same from any other from without any issue.

Comment: ya but not at the same time they are shown when i click on save and until my condition satisfies it will show the same form the text 0001 will be on Form2 text box not on Form1 text box

Comment: i got the first one as 0001 on form2 when loaded what i need is when i click on save there is no disturbance made to this form just i will clear some fields at the same time the text box value 0001 should be 0002

Comment: @Dorababu: got it, you mean till condition on first object of form2 will not setisfied the another object of form2 should not open. same object of form2 should only be open  till condition not true. right?

Comment: Ya exaclty if form closes means i can also do but here i did not know what to do

Comment: for this do this:  private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            this.Hide();
        }

Comment: have u check what i did in my form closing

Comment: Actually on form closing i handle differently what i need is this to be done on button click i would like to display the auto id to the textbox but this is not working as the form is not loading